Pointwise convergence of $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$
It is a question of pointwise convergence and I want to know whether I did it in the correct way or not.
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$
By dividing with $x^n$, i got
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^n}}$= $\frac{1}{0+1}$= 1
Is this method and anwser correct?

What's the point of writing that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$?

Sorry by mistake

Yes, correct (except that it'd be clearer to write $\frac1{1+0}$ instead of $\frac1{0+1}$). Alternatively: $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=1-\frac1{1+x^n}\to1-\frac1\infty=1-0=1$. You could also first substitute $y=x^n$ to reduce to the case $n=1$ (but without real gain).

@AnneBauval Many teachers will not allow the use of $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$. Although it is correct if you are in the context of extended real numbers, that's usually not the case when one is learning Calculus for the first time.

TinCan: I agree with @jjagmath but no need for the extended real line. Simply consider $\lim\dots=\frac1\infty=0$ as an abreviation for $\lim\dots=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1t=0$.

Hmm wait, this was too easy, and your post is tagged pointwise-convergence and begins with It is a question of pointwise convergence. So I suspect you should not have evaluated the limit as $x\to\infty$ (for $n$ fixed) but the limit as $n\to\infty$ (for $x$ fixed such that this limit exists). If so, this is a triplicate.

Okay I got it now. Thanks!
